# Pegar índice de uma div com classes iguais usando mouseover() Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho várias `divs` com a mesma classe e preciso de uma função que, quando eu passar o mouse em alguma delas, com `mouseover()` pegue o índice dela

Comment: Ajuda se você mostrar o código...

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, já obtive resposta

Comment: Marque a resposta, então. Não deixe a pergunta aberta.

Comment: O gajo que respondeu a isto fez magia, continuo a pensar que esta pergunta é de baixa qualidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando diz posição `eq()` seria a index do elemento?

Caso seja, você pode usar `.index()`

```
$(element).mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Criei um pequeno exemplo, caso seja isso:

```js
$(function(){
    $("div").mouseover(function(e){
       console.log($(this).index());
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/0qon0aa8/

Comment: Exato Leonardo, era isso que eu precisava! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @GustavoSantana, marque as respostas que ajudaram. Não abandone as perguntas.